# How to control tor, when use tor proxy

Tags: python, sockets, tor

I'm trying to connect to a resource using a tor, changing identity. But after the first connection attempt to change identity causes an error.
Code:

```
import urllib2, socks, socket
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller


def newI():
    with Controller.from_port(port=9051) as controller:
        controller.authenticate()
        controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)

newI()

socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/3.0 (x86 [en] Windows NT 5.1; Sun)'} 
req = urllib2.Request('https://google.com', None, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
html = response.read()

newI()
```

I get error:

```
  File "/media/all/Run/e/c.py", line 21, in <module>
    newI()
  File "/media/all/Run/e/c.py", line 7, in newI
    with Controller.from_port(port=9051) as controller:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stem/control.py", line 659, in from_port
    control_port = stem.socket.ControlPort(address, port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stem/socket.py", line 314, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stem/socket.py", line 187, in connect
    self._socket = self._make_socket()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stem/socket.py", line 340, in _make_socket
    control_socket.connect((self._control_addr, self._control_port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/socks.py", line 369, in connect
    self.__negotiatesocks5(destpair[0],destpair[1])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/socks.py", line 236, in __negotiatesocks5
    raise Socks5Error(ord(resp[1]),_generalerrors[ord(resp[1])])
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Maybe I need to disable the proxy. Tell me how to do it correctly.

UPD:

With pycurl it's work:

```
import pycurl
import cStringIO
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller


def newI():
    with Controller.from_port(port=9051) as controller:
        controller.authenticate()
        controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)

newI()

buf = cStringIO.StringIO()
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'http://google.com/')
c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, buf.write)
c.setopt(pycurl.PROXY, 'localhost')
c.setopt(pycurl.PROXYPORT, 9050)
c.setopt(pycurl.PROXYTYPE, pycurl.PROXYTYPE_SOCKS5)
c.perform()
html = buf.getvalue()[7:]
buf.close()

newI()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `socket.socket = socks.socksocket` line.

As a temporary solution, one can keep a backup copy of `socket.socket` and use that to unset the proxy before asking Tor for a new identity, then set up the proxy again.

The code will look like this:

```
import urllib2, socks, socket
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller

old_socket = socket.socket
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

def newI():
    socket.socket = old_socket  # don't use proxy
    with Controller.from_port(port=9051) as controller:
        controller.authenticate()
        controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
    # set up the proxy again
    socket.socket = socks.socksocket

newI()

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/3.0 (x86 [en] Windows NT 5.1; Sun)'} 
req = urllib2.Request('https://google.com', None, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
html = response.read()

newI()
```

However, I am still waiting for someone to post an explanation as to why the error occurs, and a better way to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting. I wonder if...

```
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
```

is causing `_make_socket()` to get a non-standard socket, and in turn bulk. If you use [PycURL](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/to_russia_with_love.html#using-pycurl) instead does it work?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, as using PycURL is not always an option. For example, I need to use `socket.socket` directly, so I can't use PycURL instead.