# urllib over tor - Socks5Error on one computer, on other works well

Tags: python, proxy, urllib2, tor, socks

I am trying to process urllib request over tor. it's worked for me on both computers well now I don't know why but it don't work any more on one of the computers. I know that there are alot of posts about urllib over tor but it dosen't work for me.
The code with example site for checks:

```
import socket
import socks
def create_connection(address, timeout=None, source_address=None):
    sock = socks.socksocket()
    sock.connect(address)
    return sock



socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, '127.0.0.1', 9050, True)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
socket.create_connection = create_connection

import urllib2
print urllib2.urlopen("http://bm26rwk32m7u7rec.onion/index.php").read()
```

exception traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check.py", line 15, in <module>
    print urllib2.urlopen("http://bm26rwk32m7u7rec.onion/index.php").read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1181, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.get_selector(), req.data, headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 973, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1007, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 969, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 829, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 791, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 772, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "check.py", line 5, in create_connection
    sock.connect(address)
  File "/home/lior/code/socks.py", line 369, in connect
    self.__negotiatesocks5(destpair[0],destpair[1])
  File "/home/lior/code/socks.py", line 236, in __negotiatesocks5
    raise Socks5Error(ord(resp[1]),_generalerrors[ord(resp[1])])
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

tried also this code:

```
import urllib2, socks, socket
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller

old_socket = socket.socket
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

def newI():
    socket.socket = old_socket  # don't use proxy
    with Controller.from_port(port=9051) as controller:
        controller.authenticate()
        controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
    # set up the proxy again
    socket.socket = socks.socksocket

newI()

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/3.0 (x86 [en] Windows NT 5.1; Sun)'} 
req = urllib2.Request('https://google.com', None, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
html = response.read()

newI()
```

got:

```
stem        : INFO     Error while receiving a control message (SocketClosed): empty socket content
```

Comment: See this maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20304301/how-to-control-tor-when-use-tor-proxy

Comment: Checked this. Dosen't worked for me

Comment: Can you edit your question and tell what happens when you do what they say in the link?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I know the answer. Maybe it's a firewall issue - try turning it off. BTW, I know a Lior Pozin in real life, is that you? :)

Comment: Lol now I saw, Yes it's me :D